# jQuery each to iterate through inputs and store values in array

Tags: jquery, each

I have multiple hidden inputs with the name image_values:

```
<input class="imageValues<?=$category->cat_id;?>" name="image_values[]" type="hidden" value="<?=$step->img_pos.":".$option->image_path;?>" />
```

I want to iterate through each of them and store the values in an array, I am trying this below, but it isnt going inside the each at all, what am i doing wrong?:

```
var imageValues = ''; 

jQuery("input[name='image_values']").each(function(){

    imageValues = jQuery(this).val();

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use `map()` for just that. It will return a jQuery collection of that returned in the function. `.get()` converts this into a normal array.
- You also need to include the square brackets in your selector, and escape them:

```
var imageValues = jQuery("input[name='image_values\\[\\]']").map(function(){
        return this.value
}).get()
```